# read command in bash does not wait in operations with different user

Tags: bash, shell

I'm calling bash A via different user within bash B like this, and i want to stuck on line "***" untill user enters "exit".

```
# bash B
su test<<endOfTestOperation
./bashA.sh
endOfTestOperation

# bash A
# Start a process &
read LINE            <------ I want to wait here until user inputs "exit"
if [ "$LINE" == "exit" ]; then
    # end the process 
    exit
fi
```

If i call bash A only, it works fine. if i put "read" after "endOfTestOperation", it also works. So i guess the problem roots in using different permission or forked process.

[supplemental description]
What i'm trying to do is: start a tcpdump (root permission required, so bash b is ran with sudo), then start a tcpserver progress, then end the tcpserver on demanding of user input in stdin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting standard input for `su` from a here document. The command that `su` runs will inherit *its* standard input from `su`, so it is *also* the here document, not the terminal. Since `su` consumes the entire here document in reading the command to run, there is nothing left for `bashA.sh` to read, and so the `read` command fails immediately rather than waiting for input.

You'll need to post more detail about what you are actually trying to do if you want a workaround.

Comment: If i run bashA.sh without su test<<, it waits at "read" as expected. i'm considering this alternative. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Using an `if` statement will not continue to check if the input is "exit", it will only check once.

You could use an `until` loop to make sure user input is "exit".

You can find the process of the most recent command sent to the background by using `$!`.

```
background command &
pid=$!
until [[ $LINE == exit ]]; do
    read LINE
done && { kill -9 $pid; exit; }
```